# Битрикс: как получить уникальный id результата заполнения формы?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сайт на Битриксе. На нём - несколько форм обратной связи. Результаты заносятся в базу. Система присваивает каждому результату заполнения уникальный ID (независимо от того, какая форма заполнена):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как получить этот уникальный ID? Какая переменная компонента отвечает за внесение в базу этого значения?

Comment: Где, для чего и в какой момент вам нужен этот ID?

Comment: Нужен на фронтэнде, просто выводить эту цифру в виде счетчика

Comment: И все же не понятно что значит "просто". Вам нужно ИД последнего, или только что отправленного или еще что то. Поскольку суть и цель задачи не ясны. Вот общий ответ CFormResult::GetList https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/form/classes/cformresult/getlist.php

Comment: id последнего и id только что отправленного - это одно и то же. CFormResult::GetList - то, что нужно. за ссылку спасибо!

Comment: Ну не совсем одно и тоже. :) Может я вообще ни чего не отправлял, а вы мне хотите ИД какойто показать.  Опять же, а если кто-то еще эту форму заполнил, на долю секунд позже меня?  Может вам вообще правильнее воспользоваться событием формы https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/form/events/index.php  и/или просто кастомизировать шаблон компонента (в части где сообщение о заполнении)